# Listar registros con fecha mas reciente

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Tengo lo siguiente

```
List<Pago> listaPago = dbc.pagos
    .GroupBy(c => c.codigoUsuario)
    .SelectMany(w => w)
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.fechaPago)
    .ToList();
```

Y me muestra lo siguiente

```
codigoPago    codigoUsuario    fechaPago
01              Us-01          24/12/2017
02              Us-01          20/11/2017
03              Us-02          22/12/2017
```

Quiero que el resultado me muestre solo esto

```
01              Us-01          24/12/2017
03              Us-02          22/12/2017
```

...con la fecha mas actual del pago de los usuarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea del `GroupBy` es correcta, pero el `SelectMany` que le sigue basicamente anula los efectos del `GroupBy` y causa que devuelva todos los registros.

Lo que necesitas después del `GroupBy` es un `Select` (con las condiciones correctas) para que cada agrupamiento devuelva un solo objeto `Pago`:

```
List<Pago> listaPago = dbc.pagos
    .GroupBy(p => p.codigoUsuario)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.fechaPago).First()) // esta es la parte importante
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.fechaPago) // aquí puedes ordenar el resultado por lo que quieras
    .ToList();
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Es que lo estas ordenando por codigo  .GroupBy(c => c.codigoUsuario)

deberia ser por fecha  .GroupBy(c => c.fecha)